# Error while running ionic serve command

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic serve script error :
[image: ionic serve script error : click to see the error]

I am facing a sudden error from cmd-line in visual code when executing ionic serve.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities :

1. Check whether you are inside a ionic project
2. Make sure you have set npm path in yout PATH variable

   C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Thank you, sir now it's working after changing the PATH variable.@Lokkeshwaran,@McGrady.